# Customising temp. Google Doc while Google Sheets to epub conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

ref this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223064/saving-a-google-sheet-as-epub/67223348?noredirect=1#comment118848926_67223348)

With this script, all the Col A text gets converted to epub and is saved in the drive. Here, Entire data is placed in the doc continuously without page break or title-body separation.
Further, I would like to customise it.

1. The titles (chapters/insights) should be **bold** and placed in a new page.
2. Each row text should be **bold , centre aligned and in a new page** in the order:  *serial number, image (common for all), then text (row)*. This should continue until the next title, where the serial number is reset and starts from 1. *Attaching sample of expected result*.
3. The font should be 'Baskerville' and font size '20'.

Link to Sheets: [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UeakN4ZWuQpK6GZlIUFudSYQ55t5S8QoGjD4vcZqDZU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: About your sample image, what is the line between `5` and `I kind of...`? Do you want to put such designed line? And the font name of your sample image is `Baskerville`?

Comment: I saw your sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I cannot image your goal from your sample Spreadsheet and your sample image. I apologize for my poor skill. Can you add more sample image of your goal? And, in your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the empty rows are randomly inserted. How do you want to use the empty rows for your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. It's an png image. I have added the same to the sheet whose link I have put in the question. reg the font, Yes, all text should be Bold, Center-aligned, Font: Baskerville and Font Size: 20.

Comment: @Tanaike The empty rows can be ignored. I will add more samples to the sheet in 'Sample' tab. please check

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `The empty rows can be ignored. I will add more samples to the sheet in 'Sample' tab. please check`, I saw your sample Spreadsheet again. But it seems that 5 images are put. Unfortunately, from these images, I cannot still understand about your goal. For example, you want to put each row as each new page? I apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: @Tanaike No probs. Happy to clarify. Please see the link in the sheet under the desired output cell. You will understand it better.